# Error with .com dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have this project in Android Studio usin RecycletView and CardViews, so i got this error in the cardview's XML file "No resource Identifier found  for attribute 'border_color'"

My XML code looks like this

```
<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true"
        android:id="@+id/holas"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

My dependencies on AndroidMAnifest look like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

among others look-alike errors, I have no clue of what to do. 
If any of you could be gently enough to help me with this I'd really appreciate it. 
thanks

Comment: com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView is this lib  ? or your class file

Comment: I think you missed this gradle dependency compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'